# Calling Member Function Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I am having trouble calling a function pointer inside a structure.  I have used this approach before outside of classes, but now that I am trying it inside a class method using function pointers to other class methods.... I am receiving a compiler error. Here is my class:

```
class Myclass
{
    int i;

    void cmd1(int)
    {}

    void cmd2(int)
    {}

    void trans()
    {
        const struct
        {
            std::string cmd;
            void (Myclass::*func)(int)
        }
        CmdTable[] =
        {
            { "command1", &Myclass::cmd1 },
            { "command2", &Myclass::cmd2 }
        };

        CmdTable[0].func(i);
        CmdTable[1].func(i);
    }
};
```

The lines `CmdTable[0].func(i);` and `CmdTable[1].func(i);` both provide the following
error:
Error: expression must have (pointer-to-) function type.

I realize there are probably better ways of doing this, but I'm rather curious as to why what I've written doesn't work.  Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/bind).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Why? Those are very heavy-weight, expensive "solutions" for a problem that doesn't need them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer-to-member-function is a pure *class* property. You need to combine it with a class instance in order to make a meaningful function call. For example, to use the instance `*this`, you can use the operator `->*` and say:

```
(this->*CmdTable[0])(i);
```

Or you can use operator `.*` on an object value:

```
(*this.*CmdTable[0])(i);
```

The latter form is always correct. For the former, note that `operator->*` may be overloaded and do something unrelated.